# Changing the selected color of dijit.MenuItem

Tags: dojo

In my dijit Toolbar I am using a DropDownButton to hold a dijit.Menu with many MenuItems. These MenuItems control various functions in my project. The DropDownButton and Menu are declared in the html page but the MenuItems are created in runtime dynamically.

When the user clicks on a MenuItem, it will change the mode of something on the page. Currently there is no way the user knows what he/she selected last in the dropdownMenu by looking at the dropdownMenu itself. Is there a way (CSS or JavaScript) that we can force the background color of the selected MenuItem to stay until the user clicks another selection on the same dropdownmenu?

*Obviously I can show a label somewhere else telling the user what mode it is in but that will not be as intuitive as a selected feel on the dropdown menu itself.*

This is how the HTML part is declared:

```
    <button dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton" iconClass="esriLayerIcon" id="VFAContentBtn" label="Content Filter"     title="Content Filter" style="width: 200px">
    <div dojoType="dijit.Menu" id="VFAContentDDMenuMain">

     </div>
    </button>
```

This is a rough look at the runtime populate:

```
    var contentMenu = dijit.byId("VFAContentDDMenuMain");
    // add the ALl Campus regardless. 
    // For the clicked value, we will use 0 for the ALL.
    contentMenu.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({
        label : "All Campuses",
        id : "C:0",
        focused : true,
        onClick : function(evt) {CampusFilterClicked(evt)}
    }));    
    // For the individual campus, we will just use the Campus Id since the menu has campuses only.  
    for (var i = 0; i <= arrRegionCampus.length - 1; i++) {
        var campusId = Math.abs(arrRegionCampus[i].CampusId);
        var campusName = arrRegionCampus[i].CampusName;
        // the evt of the onClick will contain the information we need.
        var menuX = new dijit.MenuItem({
                            id : "C:" + campusId,
                            label : campusName,
                            onClick : function(evt) {
                                CampusFilterClicked(evt);
                            }
                        });
        contentMenu.addChild(menuX);
        menuX = null;
    }
```